# Assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: variables, pointers, warnings

I am a total newbie in C and our teacher gave us this homework, finding minimum in matrix generated from [0; MAX-1]. The matrix should be interpreted as an 1D array. The generating works OK but I can't get the minimum part to work, it should return int MINIMUM - this works, but I don't know how to link **pos_x** and **pos_y** in the **min** function with variables in **main** so I can printf them in the **main**. The warning I get is **warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]**.
Any help much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 5

void fill_random(int *m, int max){

for(int i = 0; i < N*N; i++)
    m[i] = rand() % max;
}

int min(int *m, int *pos_x, int *pos_y){

int minimum = m[0];

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        if(m[i * N + j] < minimum){
            minimum = m[i * N + j];
            pos_x = i;
            pos_y = j;
        }
return minimum;
}

int main(void){

int m[N*N];

printf("Fill random from [0;MAX-1]:\n");

int input;

printf("Enter MAX: ");
scanf("%d", &input);

fill_random(m, input);

printf("\nMinumum:\n");

int pos_x, pos_y;

min(m, pos_x, pos_y);

printf("\nMinimum is %d at [%d][%d]", min(m, pos_x, pos_y), pos_x, pos_y);
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, your arguments to the `min` function are wrong. You have defined it as expecting an `int *` - a pointer to an int. When calling it, you supply an `int`. Hence the warning.
You may be being confused by how you are passing m - but as it is an array special rules appply and m in fact is a pointer - equivalent to `&m[0]`.

I won't critique the rest of your code, that is for your teacher! I would suggest stepping through it in a debugger, watching the variables change. That should be very illuminating.